# Does opencv have a function similar to size and bwperim in matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, matlab-engine, matlab-deployment

I am new to opencv and good at matlab

i want to write equalent of below to opencv

[mm,nn]=size(binaryimage);

bwperim(binaryimage);

Please can any one help

Answer (score 2):

There is a library for these things: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib

Comment: ya i have reference manual of Opencv But is cvsize same as size in matlab

and for perimeter i didnt find similar function

Comment: it is too bad though that it uses IplImage :((

Answer (score 0):

For emulating bwperim you can do

```
Mat m;
Mat dilated = m.clone(); dilate(dilated,one_pixel_wide_element);
Mat output = dilated - m;
```

where the `one_pixel_wide_element` can be constructed [using instructions from opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html):

```
  dilation_type = MORPH_RECT;
  dilation_size = 1;
  Mat element = getStructuringElement( dilation_type,
                  Size( 2*dilation_size + 1, 2*dilation_size+1 ),
                  Point( dilation_size, dilation_size ) );
```

This gives an outer boundary. For inner boundaries do erode (and `m-eroded`).